# Elasticsearch optimum index size

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I have a 3-node cluster whose nodes have 4g ES_HEAP_SIZE each. When an index size was around 4GB there was no problem, but when the index size exceeds the 10GB it often gave Java heap space exception and Unavailableshard exception. When I decrease the index size the problem disappeared. Therefore my question is; what is the optimum index size for such a 3-node elasticsearch cluster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question of "what is the optimum index size for x-node cluster" depends on a few things:

1. How big are the average documents in your store?
2. What do your queries look like, are you doing a lot of faceting / sorting?
3. How much total memory do you have on each machine? Are these nodes on seperate machines or the same machine?
4. When you index the data, do you store=true set? (you shouldn't)
5. Are you doing anything else, like parent/child or nested docs that is memory intensive?
6. Do you index heavily or lightly?
7. What is the total number of documents in your store?

In your case, it's less about index size though, and more about having the right amount of memory allocated for your case. Moreover, I think you found your own optimum size based on current use and storage patterns without really asking.

That said, the above list of items are just a few of the things off the top of my head that you should use when trying to gauge how much memory you should allocate to the JVM.

In general, you should always leave at least 50% to the OS, and never more that 32GB (I never go more than 29GB). Other than that, I wouldn't say there is a hard and fast rule. In your case, you might find that there is room to allocate more, or you might find that you've allocated too much.

For example, let's say you have a field that you facet on, and that field is an array of longs.

Let's say the longest such array has 300 members and you are looking through 2M documents. The JVM will allocate first 300*2000000*8 (8 bytes for a java long). If that amount of space exceeds your JVM size, you will get an OOM every time.

The solution here is either A.) create a fourth node B.) allocate more memory C.) rethink your indexing/storing strategy or D.) rethink your faceting strategy.

For example, maybe you can get away with a short or an int. Maybe you don't need all 300 members, but you really only care about three for faceting. Store only those three and the long list of 300 goes to another field (that you will never facet against).

Usually the strategy is use case dependent and requires some thought and foresite into how you will be using the search cluster. One of the greatest things of elasticsearch is that you can be up and running in about five minutes, but what I've found is this leads to the illusion that elasticsearch manages everything. It manages a lot, but this still doesn't absolve from good system administration.